# Change fonts in MHCHEM environment in latex

Tags: fonts, changes

I want to change font in mhchem environment to lm roman font. How can I do that??

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is your minimal complete code in tex format?

Comment: LM Roman (or Computer Modern) is the default font in LaTeX and hence also for things typeset with `mhchem`. In general, you can just switch the font before and after the commands provided by the `mhchem` package to change the font. So, I don't really get the problem you have ...